# Let's Build an Active Chatroom for the Betterment of the Community

Tags: discussion, community, chat

This is a request for anyone and everyone who loves bicycles, no matter your rep, experience or cycling type, to come join [The Velodrome](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) chat room. I would love to see this chat room accumulate some regulars and grow into an active room.

Here are some of the major reasons why this will benefit the site as a whole:

- It is a good place to discuss questions, answers, and/or comments that need reviewing, answering, editing, etc.
- It is the perfect place to talk about questions that are deemed too opinion-based for the site or will likely solicit debate/discussion (ie *what type of bike should I buy?*)
- It will be great for discussing things that are too broad for the site like riding gear, specific builds, routes, rides, etc. (ie *how did you complete the CDT?*)
- If its anything like the SO chatrooms I am active in, it will likely grow your meme/funny pictures collection :P
- It is ideal for discussing upcoming and previous events

In my personal experience of being involved in an active SO chatroom, I can see this site stand to gain so much from people coming into chat and sharing their wisdom in a less formatted way where you don't stand to lose/gain rep based on your opinions.

**Related**: Be sure to read up on the [FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) for chat if you're not already familiar with SE Chat.

Answer (score 5):

The Velodrome still exists, but there are not a lot of users.  Sometimes days go past between lines.  Give it a go and breathe some fresh air in!

Comment: Part of it might be that for a good portion of the northern hemisphere, people aren't riding bikes right now. But in general, our chat hasn't been super active.

Comment: When you see me there it means I'm not riding! It's been happening far too much lately :-(